# How can i access this multi URL in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

How can i access this multi URL in laravel 4.2.

http://localhost/new/public/library/course/1/First%20Video

My code is

```
Route::get('library/course/{id}', function($id){
    return View::make('course')->with('id',$id);
});

Route::get('library/course/{id}/{video}', function($id, $video){
    $array = array('id' => '$id', 'video' => '$video');
    return View::make('course')->withvideos($array);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The second route you listed should work with that URL. Note that your webserver is setup abnormally -- usually you'd configure it to have URLs like `http://localhost/library/course/1/First%20Video`. If you provide additional details about your web server (Windows? Linux? Apache? Nginx?) I can assist you with that.

Comment: Its a localhost on a pc. I'm trying to get the video with the name first video but the route not working. The first route is for listing the course videos and its working well.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the URL correctly, and it should reach your second route.

But you have a bug in your route:

```
// Your code
$array = array('id' => '$id', 'video' => '$video');
```

You shouldn't put single quotes around your variables -- it should be:

```
$array = array('id' => $id, 'video' => $video);
```

The single quotes force PHP not to resolve the two variables, so they are simply literal strings -- not what you want here.

Also, to pass the parameters to the view, you should adjust your code to use:

```
return view('course', $array);
```

Comment: Alright but the course.blade.php is accepting the parameters with the first route only. What changes or code should i write to this course page to access the second route

Comment: I've edited my comment to show how to correctly pass variables to the view. Note that you could also use `return View::make('course', $array);`

Comment: I know you right. But what I'm asking is how to grab the array elements in the courses.blade.php page. I'm using the below code and i know its wrong


@foreach($Videos as $video)
    {{ $video['id']; }}
   @endforeach

Comment: That's a completely new question, John. Post it with some details and I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: can't you help me here

Comment: I need more details -- it's hard to do this in comments, and I get no additional reputation for doing so. For example, the code you just posted uses a variable called `$Videos`, but that's the first I've seen of that variable, so I have no idea where it's coming from.