# How to handle two parameters in laravel when passing from a route to a page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm passing the below two routes

```
Route::get('library/course/{id}', function($id){
    return View::make('course')->with('id',$id);
});

Route::get('library/course/{id}/{video}', function($id, $video){
    $array = array('id' => '$id', 'video' => '$video');
    return View::make('course')->withvideos($array);
});
```

Both the routes are working properly but just one by one to the course.blade.php page. If i remove the content of first route then the 2nd route works otherwise it gives me an error. How can i handle these both routes on the page?

******UPDATED

The code of my course page is the following.
Note only I'm using the first route in this page. I'm unable to use the second as it gives an error.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')



    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <?php $coursesName = DB::table('topics')->select('title')->get(); ?>
            <ul class="side-nav">
                @foreach($coursesName as $courseName)
                <li><a href="#">{{ $courseName->title }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="large-8 columns" data-equilizer>
            <?php $courseViews = DB::table('courses')->whereid($id)->get();  ?>

            @foreach($courseViews as $courseView)

                <?php $requiredId = $courseView->id; ?>

                <?php  $courseVideos = DB::table('videos')->whereid($requiredId)->get(); ?>

                @foreach($courseVideos as $courseVideo)
                    <!--<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ $courseVideo->link }}?color=ff9933&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0' width='700' height='400' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen"></iframe>-->
                    <br>
                    <a href="{{ $courseView->id }}/{{ $courseVideo->id }}">{{ $courseVideo->name }}</a>
                @endforeach

            @endforeach


        </div>



    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the content of the `course.blade.php` file here? I tried with your routes and it works for both routes on my local machine.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: You already asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840122/how-can-i-access-this-multi-url-in-laravel-4 but you didn't update your broken code when asking this new question. I don't understand.

Comment: i updated my question with the code reference. Check it out. Hope it helps you in giving me solution.

Answer (score 0):

If think that your error is here: `$array = array('id' => '$id', 'video' => '$video');`

When you write `'$id'` it will assigned a string and not use the content of the variable.

Try te change this line by `$array = array('id' => $id, 'video' => $video);`

**Note:** You can use `[]`instead of `array()` if you use PHP 5.4+

Comment: I already told him this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840122/how-can-i-access-this-multi-url-in-laravel-4 -- not sure why he's still pasting this broken code.

Comment: i updated my question with the code reference. Check it out. Hope it helps you in giving me solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Romain Lanz also I like to mention if you write your route like this

```
Route::get('library/course/{id}', function($id){
    return View::make('course')->with('id',$id);
});

Route::get('library/course/{id}/{video}', function($id, $video){
    $array = array('id' => '$id', 'video' => '$video');
    return View::make('course')->withvideos($array);
});
```

> It will always match **`'library/course/{id}'`** rather
>   **`'library/course/{id}/{video}'`**

You should write your route like this

```
Route::get('library/course/{id}/{video}', function($id, $video){
    $array = array('id' => $id, 'video' => $video);//Also change your array value
    return View::make('course')->withvideos($array);
});

Route::get('library/course/{id}', function($id){
    return View::make('course')->with('id',$id);
});
```

Comment: i updated my question with the code reference. Check it out. Hope it helps you in giving me solution.